# Exception on trying to acquire a previously acquired mutex

Tags: c#, mutex, named

I have these lines of code:

```
// index is an integer
Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "MUTEX_PREFIX" + index.ToString());
mutex.WaitOne();
// Access to the shared object which should not be accessed by multiple threads.
mutex.ReleaseMutex();
```

The same logic (named mutex) is used by other threads, so I make sure the right lock is used for the right resource.

The problem is if the named `mutex` is acquired by another thread (or process), current thread gets an exception instead of get blocked on the second line.

What I need is waiting for a named `mutex` to be released and then continue with my code.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Don't make us guess at the exception message.

Answer (score 0):

You must call mutex.ReleaseMutex() when done.  Also you catch all exceptions and release and the rethrow;

A typical pattern is to use lock, which copes with exceptions:

```
 lock (typeof(MyClass))
 {
     .. access to the share object
 }
```